# How to create java desktop application database?

Tags: java, database

I'm developing a simple family tree application (using Jung). One of the requirement is the ability to save the graph or data that I generated.

I already looked up on Google, but most of them offer website/online kind of database. I want to be able to save the database on the desktop, and load from the same database file.

What do I need to look up for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), [HSQL DB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). All of them should suit your recommodations, so the choice is up to you.

Or you can always store your data into file like XML or property file. It depends how big your app is going to be and what kind of data are you trying to save.

Comment: thnks for the quick reply. i dont have any experience with creating application database, but websites database. If i use SQLlite, do i need to access localhost when i want to load the data? if that the case, then thats not what i want. can you please clarify?

Comment: No, you don't need server(localhost) for that. Your DB is saved in file on the disc and you can access it via JDBC (which is only requirement for running SQLite).

Comment: Here is link for some tutorials and JDBC driver http://biese.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/sqlite-in-java-quickly/

Answer (score 1):

Look at embeddable databases. The good choice for you will be JavaDB http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html which is included in JDK.

Answer (score 0):

1. SQLite
2. XML
3. Your own format to store serialized objects